# How do I download Rev. 9 Third-Party add-ons?

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

The [Rev 9 add-ons site URL](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list.xml) in `SDK Manager` is no longer valid.

The only way out (that I found so far) is to accept the forced upgrade to Rev 15 SDK Tools.

But, for various reasons, I do not wish to upgrade to Rev 15 SDK.

I want to stay with Rev 9 (for now).

Is there a way to download Rev 9 only add-ons? A URL to add or replace the existing one?

Specifically, I am interested in downloading [In-app Billing Sample Application](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download) into `%ANDROID_HOME%\extras\google\market_billing\`.

How do I do this?

For reference, thanks to the comments and answer below, I discovered that the entire list of `source.properties` files under `%ANDROID_HOME%` in my current system is:

```
add-ons\addon_google_apis_google_inc_8\source.properties
docs\source.properties
google-market_licensing\source.properties
google-usb_driver\source.properties
platform-tools\source.properties
platforms\android-3\source.properties
platforms\android-4\source.properties
platforms\android-7\source.properties
platforms\android-8\source.properties
platforms\android-9\source.properties
platforms\android-Honeycomb\source.properties
samples\android-7\source.properties
samples\android-8\source.properties
samples\android-9\source.properties
samples\android-Honeycomb\source.properties
tools\source.properties
```

Comment: I don't know of an alternative URL for older revisions, but I can tell you that if you find such a URL, the files to look for are (1) `%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools\source.properties` for "Third party Add-ons" and (2) `%USERPROFILE%\.android\repositories.cfg` for "User Add-ons".

Comment: @an00b Thanks but editing `%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools\source.properties` seems to have NO effect on SDK Manager. Any other files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Android SDK Rev 15 installed. If I look in android-sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google_inc_-9\source.properties, this is the add-ons XML URL for Rev 9:
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml

Based on the XML data, the Market Billing zip is here:
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/market_billing_r01.zip

EDIT: Here are the contents of the source.properties file:

```
### Android Tool: Source of this archive.
#Mon Dec 12 00:00:15 EST 2011
Pkg.Desc=Android + Google APIs, API 9, revision 2
Pkg.License=REMOVED_TO_SAVE_SPACE
Addon.Name=Google APIs
Archive.Arch=ANY
Pkg.DescUrl=http\://developer.android.com/
Archive.Os=ANY
Pkg.SourceUrl=https\://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
Pkg.Revision=2
Pkg.Obsolete=
Addon.Vendor=Google Inc.
AndroidVersion.ApiLevel=9
```

Comment: This is incredible. +1 already. Unfortunately however, replacing the existing URL in `%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools\source.properties` as an00b suggested doesn't seem to have any effect on SDK Manager: It keeps attempting to download from the old invalid URL. Do you know how I can "feed" your URL into SDK Manager?

Comment: Another idea: change your computer's HOSTS file to map dl-ssl.google.com to your own web hosting space, then use .htaccess files in your web hosting account to deliver the proper files. This is a lot of work though -- perhaps it may be simpler to update to Rev 15?

Comment: You're right about perhaps being simpler to update to Rev 15, but I am now interested in this to see if what I am trying to accomplish is at all possible (I have manually downloaded the ZIP file, so I may be all set). Also, there may be other programmers in the future, facing the same challenge, and a confirmed working solution/workaround could be very helpful to them. So, my question now: The `source.properties` file that you listed above - what directory is it in?

Comment: In Rev 15, it's in android-sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google_inc_-9\source.properties. Don't know if the path is different in Rev 9.

Comment: That path doesn't exist in my system. All there is (for add-ons) is `android-sdk\add-ons\addon_google_apis_google_inc_8\source.properties`. Also, the path `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list.xml` doesn't exist in any of the 16 `source.properties` files in the system, so it seems that this path is shoved into my system's throat via a remote XML. I give up. I am going to update to Rev 15 (anticipating side-effects, as always in those updates).

Comment: You need to make sure that you have the Google APIs for API level 9 installed -- that should get you the v9 folder. Don't know about how you can feed the XML though. As far as the Rev 15 update, you would have had to deal with it sooner or later. :)

Comment: You're right again, but I didn't install `Google APIs for API level 9` back then and now it's too late. I managed to create a project from the downloaded ZIP you pointed at and so far there are no build errors. I managed to defer the Rev 15 update for now. Let's see what happens...

Comment: I ended up upgrading to R16 and, just as I anticipated, that started an entire new nightmare of incompatibilities. For example, the old `proguard.cfg` generates lots of errors. I now need to go an clean them one by one. On the positive side, this SDK 16 comes with `Lint`. Who said Eclipse+ADT sucks? ;)

Comment: There's also an issue with R.java values which no longer have the `final` keyword and are causing switch statement errors: http://groups.google.com/group/adt-dev/browse_thread/thread/c038f4f7ade3e023